# Detect Youtube video change with injected javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I am building an extension (some injected js) that adds some buttons to a youtube page, which works fine. My issue is that when a user clicks on another video (say in the right hand side list), the next video is loaded without an actual page reload. Is there any way to detect this change so that I can rerun my code?

I have already tried things like binding to the `hashchange` event, to no avail.

Comment: Looks like it uses `history.pushState()` to change the URL and the video. Read this answer to know how to proceed further: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5134732/921204

Comment: Using the solution given by that link, it works when using the forward/back browser buttons, but I am still unable to trigger code when a video is clicked on.

Comment: Is popState not triggered when you open a new video? Even though its name is *pop*State, i think i read somewhere that it is triggered whenever the URL changes because of a pushState or replaceState operation.

Comment: Nope. If I click on a video nothing triggers. If I then click the browser back/forward buttons `onpopstate` triggers.

Comment: How about and interval checking the source of the video frame?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The idea is simple:

- Use `background.js` to listen for url changes to a specific youtube tab using `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`
- Once tab change is detected, send the new URL to the content-script running in that tab

The background page listens for URL changes to **other** tabs also but I'm pretty sure you can figure out how to fix that.

***manifest.json***

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Tab url change detection",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": {
        "persistent":true,
        "page":"bg.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
            "matches": ["http://www.youtube.com/*"],
            "js": ["app.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://www.youtube.com/*"
    ]
}
```

***background.html***

```
<script src="background.js"></script>
```

***background.js***

```
//Listen for when a Tab changes state
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
    if(changeInfo && changeInfo.status == "complete"){
        console.log("Tab updated: " + tab.url);

        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {data: tab}, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });

    }
});
```

***app.js***

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    //here we get the new 
    console.log("URL CHANGED: " + request.data.url);
});
```

Comment: Looks good. I'll mark as answer after i've had a bit of a trial of this method.

Comment: Test it out as a new app first then build on it. Lemme know if you find problems.

Comment: @1337holiday you have the `tabId` as a parameter of your callback, you don't need to query to get a tab id.

Comment: @rsanchez yepp, thats something i was meaning to change, i was getting some weird error when i used `tabId` which is why i left it as that, ill verify that `tabId` works and change it

Comment: I am getting `Tab updated: undefined` any chance metod is deprecated or something?

Comment: @rohan-patel Dyou ever figure it out? Getting the same thing, and considering the official chrome-extension guide for google is out of date I don't have high hopes...

Comment: I do not think so. It was a group project for my course and can't recall if it worked or not. Maybe I have to open the project and see what I did.

Comment: Nice and smooth as silk. Thank You.

Answer (score 9):

I know it's an old thread but I hope someone else will be able to use this information.

I had a similar issue building a chrome extension for youtube. To be more specific I needed to detect the navigation within youtube.

**TL;DR;**
After going over most of the StackOverflow, I've ended with the following in the `context.js` file.

```js
function run(){
// your youtube extention logic 
console.log('change');
}

window.onload = run;
window.addEventListener('yt-navigate-start', run,   true);
```

**Explanation**
In case you wish to see all of the window events you can run `getEventListeners(window)`.

youtube has a costume event when changing pages, the **event is `yt-navigate-start`**.

For the first time youtube loads, I used the  `window.onload` and after that, add the event listener `window.addEventListener('yt-navigate-start', run,   true);`

Good luck, I hope this could help.

Comment: doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Hi @PrateekChaubey just checked it and it seems to work 

the answer below works as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/59471551/1627640

Answer (score 3):

I was recently struggling with this and I figured out what to do. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it doesn't rely on a `background.js` file.

```
var oldURL= ""

//window.setInterval takes a function and executes it after 
//a given time (defined by the second parmeter)in miliseconds

var urlChangeHandler = window.setInterval(checkUrlChange, 500)

function checkURLChange(){
  newURL = document.URL;
  if(newURL !== oldURL){
   doSomething();
   oldURL = newURL;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will be helpful for somebody.

```
var old_url = '';
var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
            if (location.href != old_url) {
                old_url = location.href;
                console.log('URL was changed');
            }
    });
});

mutationObserver.observe(document.documentElement, {childList: true, subtree: true});
```